# Are their differences between lua 5.1 bytecode created using luac and string.dump()?

Tags: lua, bytecode

If so, is there any way to convert between the two?

I'm trying to load some byte code created by string.dump into a program called unluac, however it is not working.

Here are the bytes I am attempting to decompile if it helps anyone:

```
\27\76\80\72\1\0\0\0\146\10\2\0\161\10\2\0\9\0\0\0\21\0\0\0\228\11\200\0\130\90\116\0\224\159\228\0\152\117\220\0\228\11\200\0\126\238\144\0\228\11\200\0\130\90\116\0\42\128\222\0\122\130\173\0\158\151\177\0\194\172\181\0\6\107\218\0\240\79\114\0\78\149\226\0\90\217\140\0\224\159\228\0\84\183\183\0\224\159\228\0\86\109\169\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\2\0\0\0\21\0\0\0\228\11\200\0\130\90\116\0\224\159\228\0\152\117\220\0\228\11\200\0\126\238\144\0\228\11\200\0\130\90\116\0\42\128\222\0\122\130\173\0\158\151\177\0\194\172\181\0\6\107\218\0\240\79\114\0\78\149\226\0\90\217\140\0\224\159\228\0\84\183\183\0\224\159\228\0\86\109\169\0\0\0\0\0\1\0\0\0\1\0\0\0\8\0\0\0\21\0\0\0\188\138\224\0\14\67\161\0\90\217\140\0\94\69\112\0\12\141\175\0\58\48\108\0\22\27\104\0\194\172\181\0\114\170\230\0\40\202\236\0\22\27\104\0\78\149\226\0\58\48\108\0\234\45\157\0\194\172\181\0\190\64\210\0\122\130\173\0\6\107\218\0\224\159\228\0\150\191\234\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\2\0\0\0\1\0\0\0\36\0\0\0\21\0\0\0\188\138\224\0\14\67\161\0\90\217\140\0\94\69\112\0\12\141\175\0\58\48\108\0\22\27\104\0\194\172\181\0\114\170\230\0\40\202\236\0\22\27\104\0\78\149\226\0\58\48\108\0\234\45\157\0\194\172\181\0\190\64\210\0\122\130\173\0\6\107\218\0\224\159\228\0\150\191\234\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\123\10\2\0\4\0\0\0\6\0\0\0\224\159\228\0\4\181\232\0\226\85\214\0\188\138\224\0\40\202\236\0\0\0\0\0\3\0\0\0\154\153\153\153\153\153\27\192\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0
```

Comment: According to Vlad's answer, you need 64-bit `luac`.  Probably, you have 32-bit one.

Answer (score 3):

There is no difference. Both cases will use the same `luaU_dump()` at the end.

Note though that Lua is saving sizes of some native types in bytecode chunk header. One of those fields is of type `size_t`, that makes bytecode incompatible not only between hosts with different endianness, but also between 32- and 64-bit systems.

In short - you must use Lua compiler (luac) of the same version as interpreter, and compiled for exactly the same platform that will run the interpreter. I.e. you can't use 64-bit luac to produce bytecode to be running by Lua VM within 32-bit program.